# How to bypass or avoid a column update when using a prepared statement in the same method?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Let me be clear with the problem - I have a query used to update a few columns in an Oracle table:

```
UPDATE MED_COM_MAPPER_CMDS SET STATUS = ?, OUTAGE_ID = ? WHERE CMD_ID = ?
```

I want to conditionally *not* update the `OUTAGE_ID` column value table unless I have a particular value in the `STATUS` column. How can I implement this within the same method as shown below? Changes to the method are acceptable, but not too many. Is it not possible to do this in the same method shown by the below lines of code ?

```
Connection connection = DatabaseUtil.getConnection();
preparedStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(status));

// On a condition, how can i avoid updating this column value.
// That means keep intact what it is in the DB.
preparedStatement.setString(2, outage_id); 
preparedStatement.setString(3, cmd_id);

int i = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();
```

This is to just to make it simple. It can be done by overriding the query or the method or by if conditions with increment of index value.

Hope I've been clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about change the update statement, something like:

```
UPDATE MED_COM_MAPPER_CMDS 
SET STATUS = :stat, 
OUTAGE_ID = decode(status, 'X', :new_val, outage_id)
WHERE CMD_ID = blah
;
```

If status = 'X' (the existing status value that is), then update outage_id with new_val, else keep existing outage_id.

Comment: To get the existing values of the OUTAGE_ID column, before that i need to run SELECT query. right ?

Comment: @Hari no, thats part of the update, you don't need anymore selects or pass in anything else.  Oracle will know the existing OUTAGE_ID value for each row that returns for this where clause, and only update OUTAGE_ID to "new_val" if the existing status field = 'X'

Answer (score 1):

You can add a NULL check on the input value: if the passed in value is NULL, then set the column value to the same value it already has, otherwise set it to the passed in value. This example uses Oracle's NVL, but you could use COALESCE or something else.

```
UPDATE MED_COM_MAPPER_CMDS SET STATUS=NVL(?, STATUS) WHERE CMD_ID=?
```

Comment: To get the existing values of the STATUS column, before that i need to run SELECT query. right ?

Comment: @Hari Nope, same as tbone's response.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query:

```
UPDATE MED_COM_MAPPER_CMDS SET STATUS=? WHERE CMD_ID=?
```

If you want that to happen conditionally, you can create the `PreparedStatement` using one of the below two SQLs.

```
final String SQL1 = "UPDATE MED_COM_MAPPER_CMDS SET STATUS=? WHERE CMD_ID=?";
final String SQL2 = "UPDATE MED_COM_MAPPER_CMDS SET STATUS=?, OUTAGE_ID=? WHERE CMD_ID=?";


Connection connection=DatabaseUtil.getConnection();

if(condition) {
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL1);
    statement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(status));
    statement.setString(2, cmd_id);
    int i = statement.executeUpdate();
} else {
    statement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(status));
    statement.setString(2, outage_id);
    statement.setString(3, cmd_id);
    int i = statement.executeUpdate();
}

connection.commit();
```

Comment: I think, my question was not clear. The condition is not change the query. Use the same query but not to update outage_id column/.

Comment: then what solution do you suggest. Just write another method.

Comment: An if condition for an single column to check. How about if there are more than 20 columns and randomly choose them to update the column or not ?

Comment: You never told that. You can't do that dynamically. And if you managed to do, you wouldn't benefit from prepared statement caching provided by your container at all. Think about it.

Comment: what the problem if you update with the same value in the column?

Comment: Damodar, i have to run select query before that.

Comment: It sounds like you want your method to run a query that is dynamically created at run-time ("sometimes I need to update columns 1,2,3, the next time I might need to update columns 4,5,6, the next time, 1,6,8"). Although they may be clever ways to do this with only one query, it seems to me they will make the code harder to read. Better to make it clear the query is dynamically created, I think.